# Transforming view - all the subviews don't transform the same way as it's parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, transform

Basically, I'm creating a stackable tinder like app, where the views need to shrink as they go back in the stack. Like so:

[image]

I have already implemented it by changing the actual frames of the objects, but when resizing the images would glitch so I am trying transforming the objects instead

```
self.cardNib.frame = self.cardView.frame;

CGAffineTransform moveTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(yValue/2, yValue);

self.cardNib.transform = moveTransform;
```

This code works fine, and the views nicely move along the yaxis and xaxis along their identity. However, when I add this line in the views look how I want them so, but the subviews are all wrong not centered and too small :

```
CGAffineTransform moveTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0 - transformWidthIncrement, 1.0);
```

I just want to scale the objects so they are smaller, and make sure the subviews scale correctly too.

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could add some images.

Comment: you could use iCarousel https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: I have a lot of functionality already (uppangesture, back next buttons). I'm not looking to use a library, thanks though.

Comment: you need to tell the view heirarchy in more detail. not sure how they are not being scaled with the views. To me they look fine in the screenshot

Comment: the subviews should stretch so the width of the whole view - as you can see the video is now smaller than the view

Comment: and how was it looking originally ? please comment using the @ so that i get notified of the response.